# Laravel 5.7: Class setQueue does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue

Getting this error when trying to send a simple email:

> Class setQueue does not exist at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779)

Here is the code causing it:

```
Mail::raw($data['email_body'], function (Message $message) use ($email_or_url, $data) {
    $message->to($email_or_url);
    $message->subject($data['email_subject']);
});
```

Why would Laravel be trying to queue this and how do I make it stop?

Comment: did you set QUEUE_CONNECTION in your .env config?

Comment: It is set to `sync`...I don't even want it to queue at all. I want it to send immediately.

Comment: I haven't encounter the same issue when using Mail::raw() in my current Laravel 5.7 project, did you upgraded from previous version recently?

Comment: No this is a fresh 5.7 install.

Comment: It looks like this is now a known issue and acknowledged by Laravel dev team, potentially related to PHP 7.3: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26819

Answer (score 1):

bug case in laravel project for this issue. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26819

It turned out to be a problem in php. Laravel has patched it so you have 2 options to fix. Use the patch version and hope there aren't other places php 7.3 breaks laravel, or downgrade your project to 7.2

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue in MacBook Pro. For MacBook Users just use command

> "valet restart"

In my case, it's working now. Try to restart your server that might be helpful.

**Note: I am using PHP 7.3.***

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you rename your `QUEUE_DRIVER` environment variable to `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in both `config/queue.php` and `.env` - it was renamed in 5.7

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/trying-to-send-email-class-setqueue-does-not-exist

> Why would Laravel be trying to queue this and how do I make it stop?

It's not trying to queue *this* email, but `MailServiceProvider` still registers a queue driver (for when an email implements the `ShouldQueue` interface).

Comment: What is bizarre is this error only happens in production and not in my local env.

Comment: Are you caching config on production? Have you re-run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: I haven't cached the config on local or production.

Comment: Perhaps run a `php artisan config:clear` and  `composer dump-autoload` just to rule it out? (After double checking that the variable is renamed in both places)

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me because i was running php 7.3, when i downgrade to php 7.2.13 it works, and i also change the QUEUE_DRIVER variable in .env and config/queue.php

Answer (score 0):

What I've found by now in my research for the solution is that in my case it is not about the php version (I even reinstalled everything and changed my servers providers because of the laracasts answers) but it was a code caused error, and I know because i reverted to previous commit and it worked fine.

In **my** case it was because I had a transaction before the email sending

```
$suma = $user->transactionsAsUser->filter(
            function ($transaction) {
                return $transaction->status == 'successful' || $transaction->kanjea_ammount < 0;
            }
        )->sum('kanjea_ammount');
        $user->kanjea_balance = $suma;
        $user->save();
\Mail::to($user->email)->send(new \App\Mail\JustRegistered($user));
```

When I removed that fragment before the last line, it just worked fine. Even using PHP 7.3.

By the way. this problem doesn't occur in my local environment w7+xampp, but only dokku

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to `valet install` again as I got the error after running `brew update/upgrade`

related details:
`PHP 7.3.0 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 11:00:11) ( NTS )`